# Intl.DateTimeFormat produces wrong format

Tags: javascript, internationalization, react-intl

In current Chrome, Firefox and Safari `Intl.DateTimeFormat` for the locale `it-CH` (italian part of Switzerland) is wrong:

```
new window.Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-CH').format(new Date()) // -> "6/7/2017"
new window.Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-CH').format(new Date()) // -> "06.07.2017"
new window.Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-CH').format(new Date()) // -> "06.07.2017"
```

The output of the first line is wrong. In all parts of Switzerland the format should be "dd.mm.yyyy"

Interestingly IE11 & Edge produce the correct output for the above snippet.

What is the best way to fix/patch/override the faulty implementation of window.Intl in given browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about best but the easiest should be something like this:

```
var nativeDateTimeFormat = window.Intl.DateTimeFormat;
window.Intl.DateTimeFormat = function(locale) {
  var native = nativeDateTimeFormat(locale);
  if (locale === 'it-CH') {
    native.format = function() {
      return nativeDateTimeFormat('fr-CH').format();
    }
  }
  return native;
}
```

This solution uses the fact that `fr-CH` has the correct format that `it-CH` should have.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems not to work in Chrome.
Setting the `format` function on the native `DateTimeFormat` seems not possible. Setting it does simply have no effect ...

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077313/understanding-intl-datetimeformat-as-a-javascript-object

Comment: @jbandi Ah, I see. Hopefully you could use the code from my suggestion in a utility function and use that, but if you're relying on a 3rd party library that uses `Intl.DateTimeFormat` internally that's of course not an option, unfortunately.