# Understanding Intl.DateTimeFormat as a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, datetime-format, ecmascript-intl

I do not understand the behavior of `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.

It does not expose the behavior I would expect from a JavaScript object. 
I would like to understand why?

The following snippet demonstrates that the `format` method on `DateTimeFormat` can't be overridden. How is this possible?

```
const itDateTimeFormat1 = new window.Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-CH');
const originalFormat = itDateTimeFormat1.format;
itDateTimeFormat1.format = function(date){ return 'Overriden! ' + originalFormat(date)};
console.log(itDateTimeFormat1.format(new Date())); // -> 13/7/2017
```

Also deriving from `DateTimeFormat` via prototypal inheritance seems not possible. The following snippet throws an error:

```
const itDateTimeFormat2 = new window.Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-CH');
const wrappedDateTimeFormat = Object.create(itDateTimeFormat2);
wrappedDateTimeFormat.format = function(date){ return 'Overriden! ' };
console.log(wrappedDateTimeFormat.format(new Date()));
// Firefox:
// TypeError: Intl.DateTimeFormat.prototype.format called on value that's not an object initialized as a DateTimeFormat
// Chrome:
// Uncaught TypeError: Method format called on incompatible receiver #<DateTimeFormat>
```

Why is `DateTimeFormat` not behaving like a "normal" JavaScript object?

How is it possible for `DateTimeFormat` to prevent overriding a method?

How is it possible for `DateTimeFormat` to prevent overriding on a derived object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original answer

Well, since it's a built-in object - it is good to have it frozen.
But you can do things like this just in Javascript with [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

See the following snipper. You can prevent override of your properties with `writeable: false`. (I've used JS 5.1)

```
var MyCoolConstructor = function () {

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'nonWriteable', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function () {return 42;}
  });
};

var instance = new MyCoolConstructor();


console.log(instance.nonWriteable()); //42
instance.nonWriteable = function () {return 'overriden';}
console.log(instance.nonWriteable()); //42
```

How to prevent prototypal inheritance?

Check this simple snippet. You can just check if current context have the same prototype as your constructor.

```
var MyCoolConstructor = function () {
  this.foo = function () {
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === MyCoolConstructor.prototype) {
      return 42;
    } else {
      throw new Error('bad this');
    }
  };
};

var instance = new MyCoolConstructor();
console.log(instance.foo());
//42

var instance2 = Object.create(instance);
console.log(instance2.foo())
//Bad this
```

## Edit 2

Derived object method override can also be prevented in the same manner,
they derive property config.
Check this snippet which is combination of previous 2

```
var MyCoolConstructor = function () {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', {
    value: function () {
      if (Object.getPrototypeOf(this) === MyCoolConstructor.prototype) {
        return 42;
      } else {
        throw new Error('bad this');
      }
    },
    writeable: false
  });
};

var instance = new MyCoolConstructor();
console.log(instance.foo());
//42

var derivedInstance = Object.create(instance);
derivedInstance.foo = function () {
  return 'overriden';
};
console.log(derivedInstance.foo());
//Bad this. Can't be overridden because foo property is not writeable
```

### Not cool hacks in 3.. 2.. 1..

If you really want to override smth, `Object.defineProperty` come to the rescue.

```
const itDateTimeFormat2 = new window.Intl.DateTimeFormat('it-CH');
const wrappedDateTimeFormat = Object.create(itDateTimeFormat2);
Object.defineProperty(wrappedDateTimeFormat, 'format', {value: function(date) { return 'Overridden!' + date.toString(); }})
wrappedDateTimeFormat.format()
//"Overriden! ..."
```

#### Conclusion

As we've seen with the examples. System objects behaves just like normal configured javascript objects

Comment: Thanks this explains a lot. However it seems in the case of `DateTimeFormat` a derived object can't provide its own `format` method (I adjusted the second snippet in the question). How is that possible?

Comment: @jbandi let me think :) I'll try to provide snippet for this behavior also

Comment: Great examples! Thanks!